# Javascript array Swapping

Tags: javascript

I have javascript array

```
var s=[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"},{"3":"three"},{"ALL":"ALL"}];
```

Here i want to check the condition,If BMW is present in the array.I want to move this "BMW" to zero position and existing zeroth value moved next(ist position) to the ALL.

Please give some suggestions or answers for how to handle this scenario,

Thanks in Advance.

Chaitu

Comment: The code you posted is invalid. Could you please post your actual code? EDIT: Question has been updated with corrected code.

Comment: Why do you put this object in an array? And are these values even valid? I think the following would do too:

`var s = { 1 : 'one', 2: 'two', ALL: 'ALL' }`

Comment: Do you really need to swap arbitrary elements, or are you trying to sort the array?  If you're sorting, there's an easier way.

Comment: @PatricK:I corrected code as per andre_roesti.

Comment: Your array declaration is not valid. Could you correct it?

Comment: @Dave: I dont want to sort,I wantnks to move ALL value to zero based postion based on condition.Thanks

Comment: Please stop changing the question.

Comment: This { 1 : 'one', 2: 'two', ALL: 'ALL' } is NOT an array and can not be sorted..

Answer (score 2):

In your most recent revision of the question, you're no longer using an Array. As such there is no actual position. There's only properties and values in no guaranteed order.

---

Your previous version looked like this:

```
var s=[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"},{"3":"three"},{"ALL":"ALL"}];
```

and could be accomplished like this:

```
for( var i = 0,len = s.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( "ALL" in s[i] ) {
        s.unshift( s[i] );
        s.splice(i+1,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without looping over all the elements.

Comment: You can do a `.sort()` as in [@BGerrissen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903256/javascript-array-swapping/4903424#4903424). I'm not sure if it will affect the other items in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s=[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"},{"3":"three"},{"ALL":"ALL"}]
for ( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ )
{
    if ( typeof s[i]['ALL'] != 'undefined' && s[i]['ALL'] != null && s[i]['ALL'] == 'ALL' )
    {
        s.unshift( s.splice(i, 1) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without looping over all the elements.

Comment: You need position of "ALL" element to splice it. If you use if ( typeof s['ALL']['ALL'] != 'undefined' && s['ALL']['ALL'] != null && s['ALL']['ALL'] == 'ALL' ) then you need another array iteration to remove this element from its position and move it to beginning of the array (there is no way to do some array.unique() in js, and jQuery.unique() working only with arrays of DOM elements).

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.sort() with a function.

```
var s=[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"},{"3":"three"},{"ALL":"ALL"}];
s = s.sort(function(a,b){
   return ( b.ALL == "ALL" ) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

return value:
- Less than 0: Sort "a" to be a lower index than "b"
- Zero: "a" and "b" should be considered equal, and no sorting performed.
- Greater than 0: Sort "b" to be a lower index than "a".

**ADDENDUM**

Since you changed your question...

```
var s = { 1 : 'one', 2: 'two', ALL: 'ALL' }; // which is NOT an array but a literal object, BIG difference.

if ( s.ALL == "ALL" ) {
    s[ 0 ] = "ALL";
    delete s.ALL;
}
```